# bootstrap datepicker hides on selecting date ranges

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have used bootstrap datepicker. Now when i select date range other than "custom" the datepicker hides. I want to keep it visible when i select options other than "custom" and than closes on clicking "apply"

```
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
        "autoApply": true,
        "setDate": new Date(),
        "dateFormat": 'yy-mm-dd',
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    applyOnMenuSelect: false,
    "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
    "opens": "left",
    "applyClass": "btn-primary",
    "cancelClass": "hide-btn",
    "startDate": "04/14/2016",
    "endDate": "04/14/2016",
    "maxDate": "04/14/2016",
}, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' +
        end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your problem is that the **Predefined Ranges** are considered as submit button just like the apply button! and that's why the calendar will hide after you click any of the ranges.

To achieve what you want first you got to add `display: block!important` when the calendar is shown using the `show.daterangepicker` event from the library, your code will look something like this

```
$('#demo').on('show.daterangepicker',function(){
    // here we will add a class with display!important in it
    $('.daterangepicker').addClass('ishow');
});
```

Unfortunately you can't add a click event directly to the button so we will use some **delegation** and luckily jQuery got a nice simple implementation for it.

```
$('body').delegate(".applyBtn", "click",function(){
    // this will be called when the apply button is clicked
    // we will remove the ishow class to hide the menu!
    $('.daterangepicker').removeClass('ishow');
});
```

And that it! hope it helps you in your project, here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wt4zdhaj/7/) to see the solution in action.

**P.S.** : don't use the `autoApply` option like you did before!

Comment: I want to keep popup visible when i select options other than "custom" and than closes on clicking "apply"

Comment: date selection work is not quickly
it's very slow response

Comment: @Mustafa.B I believe it's because the delegation, I'm out of ideas right now and to be honest the bootstrap date range picker library sucks! it's so limited and needs a revamp!

Comment: Here try using this library http://jszen.com/jquery-date-range-picker-plugin.4.html @Mustafa.B